/etc/apt directory missing after Ubuntu 20.04 installation
I installed a bog-standard Ubuntu Server 20.04, but when I logged in for the first time (a few hours post-install), the system did not have an /etc/apt directory.
From /var/log/apt/history.log I can see subiquity installing all the system packages plus my requested openssh-server:
Start-Date: 2024-11-19  20:11:36
Commandline: /usr/bin/apt-get --quiet --assume-yes --option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io --option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold install openssh-server
Install: libwrap0:amd64 (7.6.q-30, automatic), openssh-sftp-server:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.11, automatic), ncurses-term:amd64 (6.2-0ubuntu2.1, automatic), openssh-server:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.11), ssh-import-id:amd64 (5.10-0ubuntu1, automatic)
Upgrade: openssh-client:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.5, 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.11)
End-Date: 2024-11-19  20:11:44

Following that there are a number of unattended-upgrades for example:
2024-11-19 20:11:53,566 WARNING Could not figure out development release: Distribution data outdated. Please check for an update for distro-info-data. See /usr/share/doc/distro-info-data/README.Debian for details.
2024-11-19 20:11:53,567 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2024-11-19 20:11:53,571 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=focal, o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=focal-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=focal-infra-security, o=Ubuntu,a=focal, o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=focal-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=focal-infra-security
2024-11-19 20:11:53,572 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2024-11-19 20:11:53,573 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2024-11-19 20:17:12,408 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: accountsservice apparmor apport bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs bsdutils busybox-initramfs busybox-static ca-certificates cloud-init cpio curl distro-info-data fdisk gawk gcc-10-base git git-man klibc-utils krb5-locales less libaccountsservice0 libapparmor1 libarchive13 libblkid1 libc-bin libc6 libcap2 libcap2-bin libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libelf1 libexpat1 libfdisk1 libgcc-s1 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libgnutls30 libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libklibc libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common libmount1 libncurses6 libncursesw6 libnetplan0 libnghttp2-14 libnspr4 libnss3 libpam-cap libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam0g libperl5.30 libprocps8 libpython3.8 libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libsmartcols1 libsqlite3-0 libssh-4 libssl1.1 libstdc++6 libtinfo6 libtss2-esys0 libuuid1 libuv1 libx11-6 libx11-data libxml2 locales login mount nano ncurses-base ncurses-bin netplan.io open-iscsi open-vm-tools openssl passwd perl perl-base perl-modules-5.30 procps python3-apport python3-configobj python3-cryptography python3-idna python3-jinja2 python3-pkg-resources python3-problem-report python3-requests python3-setuptools python3-twisted python3-twisted-bin python3-urllib3 python3-zipp python3.8 python3.8-minimal snapd sudo tar tzdata util-linux uuid-runtime vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny wget xxd
2024-11-19 20:17:12,414 INFO Writing dpkg log to /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log
2024-11-19 20:48:43,323 INFO All upgrades installed

Sometime after this, /etc/apt is completely gone, and apt-get fails.
Would any of these packages inadvertently have deleted it during the unattended upgrade?

I can't imagine a Ubuntu update causing /etc/apt/ to be deleted; not official package anyway (if you added a 3rd party source that shouldn't be trusted; as package scripts are run as root they of course could; but not vetting/checking 3rd party packages is the problem here!).  I have however had installs fail with an error; the installer stops & doesn't continue; which means some system directories are not present (even if the system boots; but the failed install or error during install should have prompted you to check.. problems aren't always easy to detect though)

/var/log/installer/curtin-install.log ends with curtin: Installation finished so I believe the installer finished. I didn't grep any error in it.
I am guessing that if /etc/apt was not populated by the installer, then unattended-upgrade would have failed.
